# create multidimensional arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

hi i have this code `$g=0;
    while ($g < $c)
        {
        $a[$g] = array("$groupsid[$g]");
        $g++;
        }`

which enters value in an array and the output is that

```
[Groups] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => value1
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => value2
                                    )

                            )
```

How can i change the [0] in the inner array to a string i want for example id and have something like this

```
[userGroups] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [0] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => value1
                                    )

                                [1] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => value2
                                    )

                            )
```

Answer (score 2):

Add key `id` into array definition.

```
$a[$g] = array('id' => $groupsid[$g]);
```